College comedy with boys in drag
I don't remember the name of a college comedy that I saw parts of the other day. I believe the title contains the word 'private' in it. The movie had an Animal House type of feel to it. It must be from the 70's/80's era.
Here are a couple of scenes that I remember:
Scene 1 - Male student is dressed up as a female student with lots of bad makeup on and ends up giving a female student a back rub while in a sorority house while another crossdressing male student climbs out on the window ledge and is watching until he falls to the ground.
Scene 2 - The previous scene led into this one. The second crossdressing male student sees a bunch of female students run into a locker room where he follows them and watches them shower. He hides in a steam room where an older larger woman comes in and he ends up trapped under the bench while she falls asleep.
I think the male students are part of a fraternity, and think they were dressed up as female students to get into the sorority.

Thanks Walt, 'Private School' is the one! I can't wait to check out the whole movie, the parts I saw were pretty funny.

I think it was more a private secondary school (two separate ones), not a college. But really, it doesn't make a difference.

Your memory didn't betray you: this is Private School (1983) with Phoebe Cates and Matthew Modine. From the synopsis:

Christine (Phoebe Cates), a student at an exclusive all-girls private school, is in love with Jim, who attends an academy for boys nearby. Christine's arch rival Jordan also has her eye on Jim, and she is willing to do whatever she can to steal him away. Jim's uber-slob buddy Bubba is going with Betsy, Christine's cynical friend, though he would probably be unfaithful if any other woman were willing to get near him. Bubba and his pals sneak into the girls' school dressed in drag in hopes of reaching the Promised Land (better known as the women's shower room), while Christine and Jim run away together for the weekend, though their escapade isn't as romantic as they had hoped. 

Both scenes (the back-rub followed by the peeper falling off the ledge, going to the girls' showers and getting trapped in the sauna under a heavy woman) appear there. Here's the trailer:



